# Trying to make an attachment move to another, goes in the wrong way completely

Tags: roblox

I'm trying to make an attachment go to another attachment, but for some reason it always doesn't go in the right way. It goes to the left and not to the said attachment which is in our humanoidrootpart, I'm trying to recreate the Smoker from Left 4 Dead 2, any help or changes will be appreciated!

```
local strangler = script.Parent
local smokerDrag = Instance.new("Animation")
smokerDrag.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://15857341164"

local debounce = false

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(localplayer)
    localplayer.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
        while true do
            wait(0.5)
            for _, player in ipairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
                print((player.Name .. "'s Distance is: " .. (char.HumanoidRootPart.Position - strangler.HumanoidRootPart.Position).magnitude))
                if (char.HumanoidRootPart.Position - strangler.HumanoidRootPart.Position).magnitude <= 40 and not debounce then
                    debounce = true
                    print("going to grab player")
                    strangler.HumanoidRootPart.warn_01:Play()
                    wait(1.5)

                    local attachment = strangler.HumanoidRootPart.Attachment

                    local humanoidRootPart = player.Character.HumanoidRootPart
                    local direction = (humanoidRootPart.Position - attachment.Position).unit
                    local speed = 10

                    while (humanoidRootPart.Position - attachment.Position).magnitude > 1 do
                        wait(0.1)
                        print("attempting to grab")
                        attachment.Position = attachment.Position + direction * speed * 0.1
                    end

                    attachment:Destroy()
                    debounce = false
                end
            end
        end
    end)
end)
```

I tried lerping, I tried setting the attachment vector to 0,0,0 nothing is working.

Comment: Bump, issue is still happening.

Comment: Bump, yet again..